# Javascript: Taking an input putting it between two variables and outputting it

Tags: javascript

Hi so I am trying to make a tool for myself to use where I take some essay I wrote and it puts that content in between some HTML code and spits out some HTML code I can copy and paste into a .html file and put on my web server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Work in Progress</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
function formChanged() {
var template1, content, template2;
template1 = "&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;&lt;html lang=\"en\"&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;title&gt;Post&lt;/title&gt;&lt;meta charset=\"utf-8\"&gt;&lt;meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"&gt;&lt;link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Niramit\" rel=\"stylesheet\"&gt;&lt;style&gt;*{box-sizing:border-box;font-family: 'Niramit',Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;}body{margin: 0;font-family: 'Niramit',Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;}.topnav {overflow: hidden; background-color:#333;}.topnav a {float: left; display: block; color: #2f2f2f; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;}.content {background-color: #ddd; padding: 10px;}.footer {background-color: #f1f1f1; padding: 20px; text-align: center;}&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;div class=\"topnav\"&gt;&lt;a href=\"index.html\"&gt;Main Menu&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=\"content\"&gt;&lt;p&gt;";
template2 = "&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=\"footer\"&gt;&lt;p&gt;Hi my name is Casper, I am an aspiring developer.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;If you're reading this then this was made using my first project.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;";
    var finalcontent = template1 + content + template2;
    var content = document.getElementsByName("finalcontent")[0].value;

}
</script>
        <form onsubmit="myFunction(this)">
            <input type="text" name="content"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <p id="finalcontent"></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

*I know my code isn't the cleanest though I am focusing on getting it to where it works and I understand whats going on*

This is what I have right now. I am trying to do it by having the template1 and template2 with all the code except the content of the page which I want to store somewhere else. I am not sure if I am approaching this correctly so any help is accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for the [innerHTML Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)?

Comment: Where's `myFunction` implementation?

Comment: Ricky Mo, yes though im so lost to where I dont even know if im setting this up correctly.

Comment: Alon Eitan, I am referencing it at the start of my form though considering how oblivious I am, I am probably reading from other questions and adding the completely wrong thing.

Comment: You may need something like: document.getElementId("finalcontent").innerHTML = finalcontent;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to combine the templates with your input content and display in finalcontent? This is how you do it.

```js
function formChanged(form) {
var template1, content, template2;
template1 = "&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;&lt;html lang=\"en\"&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;title&gt;Post&lt;/title&gt;&lt;meta charset=\"utf-8\"&gt;&lt;meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"&gt;&lt;link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Niramit\" rel=\"stylesheet\"&gt;&lt;style&gt;*{box-sizing:border-box;font-family: 'Niramit',Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;}body{margin: 0;font-family: 'Niramit',Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;}.topnav {overflow: hidden; background-color:#333;}.topnav a {float: left; display: block; color: #2f2f2f; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;}.content {background-color: #ddd; padding: 10px;}.footer {background-color: #f1f1f1; padding: 20px; text-align: center;}&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;div class=\"topnav\"&gt;&lt;a href=\"index.html\"&gt;Main Menu&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=\"content\"&gt;&lt;p&gt;";
template2 = "&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=\"footer\"&gt;&lt;p&gt;Hi my name is Casper, I am an aspiring developer.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;If you're reading this then this was made using my first project.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;";

    var content = form.content.value;
    var finalcontent = template1 + content + template2;
    document.getElementById("finalcontent").innerHTML = finalcontent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Work in Progress</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form onsubmit="formChanged(this);return false;">
            <input type="text" name="content"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <p id="finalcontent"></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! I still wanna try and understand what actually makes it work though :P ill work on that on my own though